# SQL Full Outer Join W/ Coalesce

Tags: sql, join

Why does this query produce duplicates in some scenarios?

```
Table_1   
ID   
1  
2  
3  

Table_2  
ID  
1  
2  
4  

Table_3  
ID  
1  
3  
4
```

Query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table_1.ID, Table_2.ID, Table_3.ID)  
FROM Table_1

FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2  
ON Table1.ID=Table_2.ID  

FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_3  
ON Table1.ID=Table3.ID;
```

Result:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
4
```

The query duplicates all values where T1 is null and T2/T3 share the same value. Duplicates are removed for any other combination.

Comment: What does "duplicates" mean? Why wouldn't it? Since you're asking why your expectations are not met, you need to give your expectations. Otherwise, what do we say except that you got what you got because that's how SQL is defined? Please don't ask for yet another definition of the parts of SQL you used. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mre].

Comment: @IanS  "FULL OUT JOIN"--I love it. There's an operator I could really get behind.

Comment: @philipxy ha ha, I hesitated for a bit but thought it was a typo worth fixing ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit hard to explain.  If you show the other ids, you will see the full range of what happens:

```
"coalesce"  "id1"   "id2"   "id3"
    1         1      1        1
    2         2      2        .
    3         3      .        3
    4         .      4        .
    4         .      .        4
```

You can see the results [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/1182).

So, You get one row because t1 & t2 create a row with `t2.id = 4` and `t1.id = null` when they don't match.  Then, you get the same thing when `t3.id = 4`.  The comparison is to `t1.id` -- so you get another row.  There is no comparison to `t2.id`.

I suspect that you intend logic more like this:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id, t3.id)
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (id) full join
     t3
     using (id);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/1188) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: The sqlfilddle you linked was helpful, thank you. I tried the above logic, it also produces duplicate values. Is the only solution to execute the query sequentially as @peterm suggested?

Comment: @N00by . . . I seemed to have copied the wrong query into the answer.